# iOS: Keyboard assertion error on UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a table view inside which I have to show two text field for each row.

```
UITextField *tfName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, baseYCordinate, 180, 30)];
        tfName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        tfName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        tfName.delegate = self;
        [tfName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Heavy" size:14]];
         tfName.tag = indexPathRow;
        [tfName addTarget:self action:@selector(tfNameDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
        [tfName resignFirstResponder];
        [tfName setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        [tfName addTarget:self
                action:@selector(tfNameFinished:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
        [cell addSubview:tfName];


 UITextField *tfLocation = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, baseYCordinate, 180, 30)];
        tfLocation.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        tfLocation.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [tfLocation resignFirstResponder];
        tfLocation.delegate = self;
        [tfLocation setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Heavy" size:14]];
        [tfLocation addTarget:self action:@selector(tfLocationDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
         tfLocation.tag = indexPathRow;
        [tfLocation setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        [tfLocation addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(tfLocationFinished:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
        [cell addSubview:tfLocation];
```

I have added the following methods:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *) textField{
    [[self view] endEditing:YES];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}

-(void)tfNameDidChange:(UITextField *)tfName{
    NSLog(@"tfName for device: %ld Value: %@", (long)tfName.tag, tfName.text);

}

-(void)tfLocationDidChange:(UITextField *)tfLocation{
    NSLog(@"tfLocation for device: %ld Value: %@", (long)tfLocation.tag, tfLocation.text);

}

-(void)tfNameFinished:(UITextField *)tfName{
    NSLog(@"tfName for device: %ld Value: %@", (long)tfName.tag, tfName.text);
    [tfName resignFirstResponder];   
}


-(void)tfLocationFinished:(UITextField *)tfLocation{
    NSLog(@"tfLocation for device: %ld Value: %@", (long)tfLocation.tag, tfLocation.text);
     [tfLocation resignFirstResponder];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I get dynamic updates for the data displayed in the table. After the update comes I call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

If the keyboard is display for any of the UITableViewCell textfield, then reloadData is causing a crash with the following error:

**Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished]**

I tried explicitly to dismiss the keyboard using

```
[[self view] endEditing:YES];
```

In that case, this line itself is causing the crash.

Please help.

Comment: hi,May i know why are you writing this line:
 [[self view] endEditing:YES];

Comment: @hpp: The crash problem occurs mainly when user clicks on the first textfield and without dismissing its keyboards goes to the second keyfield. So I am writing that line to dismiss all the keyboards related to the textfields. Saw it as a solution for some other problem on stackoverflow and used it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)tfLocationFinished:(UITextField *)tfLocation{
    NSLog(@"tfLocation for device: %ld Value: %@", (long)tfLocation.tag, tfLocation.text);
     //[tfLocation resignFirstResponder];
     [[self view] endEditing:YES];
}
```

Or try this

```
-(void)tfLocationFinished:(UITextField *)tfLocation{
    NSLog(@"tfLocation for device: %ld Value: %@", (long)tfLocation.tag, tfLocation.text);
     [tfLocation resignFirstResponder];
     //[[self view] endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: I have tried both. Still causing crash. It sometimes happen the first time around. Some times crashes after few clicks.

Comment: @Pria Did you try that in all function(`textFieldShouldReturn:`,`tfNameFinished:`)?

Comment: I found out the exact cause of the crash. But still not able to remove it. I am having a dynamic update in the table where I reload table data and if the keyboard is displayed on the screen, then reloading data is causing the crash. I have updated my question.